# Read/Write to textfile, weird problem driving me nuts

Tags: text

Ok, here is the problem, if I write and read something to a text file like this, it works, no problem:

```
fstream ff,ff2;
ff.open("simtestagain.txt",ios::out);
CString mycstring = _T("Name with spaces");
char mycharbuffer[255];         //destination buffer
size_t convertedChars = 0;      //number of characters converted
wcstombs_s( &convertedChars, mycharbuffer, mycstring.GetLength()+1, mycstring.GetBuffer(), _TRUNCATE);
ff << mycharbuffer; 

ff.close();

ff2.open("simtestagain.txt",ios::in);

ff2.getline(mycharbuffer,255);
mycstring = mycharbuffer;

ff2.close();
AfxMessageBox(mycstring);
```

Now I need to also write numbers in this file, so I do:

```
fstream ff,ff2;
int a,b;
ff.open("simtestagain.txt",ios::out);
CString mycstring = _T("Name with spaces");
char mycharbuffer[255];         //destination buffer
size_t convertedChars = 0;      //number of characters converted
wcstombs_s( &convertedChars, mycharbuffer, mycstring.GetLength()+1, mycstring.GetBuffer(), _TRUNCATE);
ff << 1 << endl;
ff << mycharbuffer << endl; 
ff << 2 << endl;

ff.close();

ff2.open("simtestagain.txt",ios::in);

//EDIT: copy/paste error, not in code //ff2 >> mycharbuffer;
ff2 >> a;
ff2.getline(mycharbuffer,255);
mycstring = mycharbuffer;
ff >> b;

ff2.close();
AfxMessageBox(mycstring);
```

Now the cstring does not work and I can`t figure out why... :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the cstring doesn't work. Does it hold nothing? Does the compiler complain? What happens?

Comment: I reasked the question somewhere else and got an answer: -->[c-read-write-to-textfile-issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665593/c-read-write-to-textfile-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Rid Of `ff2 >> mycharbuffer`**

You use `ff2 >> mycharbuffer` before you retrieve the first number. So you move the position pointer beyond that line, when you try to input the number it sees a huge long string, and I'm sure it gives you errors.

Comment: actually, this is a copy paste error, it wasnt in my actual code XD

Comment: Lol, when I glanced at it, first thing that popped up =) srrbouthat